# Force template to build off of other layout

Tags: templates, shopify, liquid

On Shopify, I'm currently trying to host a landing page for signups, and really don't want the default theme layout, which looks like this (ASCII art):

```
                              CART
XXLOGOXX
MAIN-NAV-XXXXXXXXXXXX
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
PAGE-TITLE                SIDEBAR
                          -TWEETS-
CONTENT
ONLY ABOUT 30% OF PAGE
                          -WIDGETS
                          -LOTS OF
                          (UNWIELDY)
                          WIDGETS

FOOTER WHICH TAKES UP TOO MUCH SPACE
```

Issue is, when I try to shove in a signup widget in order to try to get more control over the styling, it just takes up the small area in the content panel like an `iframe`, only an `iframe` would give me the chance to scroll around and see the image/signup widget.

I've tried creating a new layout and setting up templates to use the new layout, but I'd have to delete the old layout, which I feel is a solution similar to using a sledgehammer to kill a fly.

Is there a way I can change which layout the template should use, like changing the base template in Django and Rails? If not, is this a planned feature, and if so, how soon can I expect it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new template and use it for certain pages as follows:

1. Open your Theme Editor from the 'Theme' dropdown.
2. Click the 'add a new template' link on the left, select 'page' from the dropdown, and give it a name (e.g. 'signup).
3. Edit the new template to look however you like.
4. Create a new Page or open an existing one.
5. At the bottom of the page there should be a dropdown to select the layout for the page. Select the one you just created, then save everything.
6. When you visit the page it should render under the new layout.

If you're still having problems after following these instructions, email design@shopify.com for support.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I want to use a different _base_ template (which you call the "layout" in the Theme Editor tab), like using Django's `{% include 'base_template.html' %}`, not how to modify the template in the `{{ content_for_layout }}` area.